# Segmentation fault because of ifstream obj. sent as reference?

Tags: c++, crash, segmentation-fault, ifstream

First of all, I'm extremely sorry but I can't provide the source code (it's in my native language, anyway).
So, what I'm doing is declaring an ifstream object in a (global) function, then send it to a member-function of a class (that gets it as a reference), then that function passes it to another member function of a class that's used within the before mentioned one (also gets it as a reference). 
I have pinpointed the segmentation fault at the use for reading within the member function that's within the class that's within the other class (oh my god...), i have tried eof() just to check if it gets messed by some way, it returns 0 (as expected) without crashing, it only crashes when I try to get some data as input through the ifstream object.

Sorry for the recursive description / not providing the source code, if you want to help and have any questions, please ask and I will reply promptly.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention, sorry, I have it like this (in the member function of the "parent" class) : ifstream_obj>>integer>>string; call_to_member_function_of_child_class(same_ifstream_obj);

Answer (score 2):

> First of all, I'm extremely sorry but I can't provide the source code (it's in my native language, anyway). So, what I'm doing is declaring an ifstream object in a (global) function, then send it to a member-function of a class (that gets it as a reference), then that function passes it to another member function of a class that's used within the before mentioned one (also gets it as a reference).

So, something like this:

```
class Foo {
public:
    // appropriate constructor here
    std::ifstream &stream;
};

Foo f;
void Func() {
    std::ifstream stream("whatever");
    f.stream = stream;
}
```

Yeah that's bad.  Your stream is local to your global function. Once the function returns any references or pointers to it are invalid as it is stored with automatic storage duration.  if you want the thing to stay alive then you will need to allocate it dynamically (probably sub-optimal) or construct it within the class itself.

Comment: It looks similar to this : http://pastebin.com/szeQ4s5E  (actually, that's exactly how it happens)

Comment: @Patrunjel: I don't see a problem with that code, nor does it raise any exception when I run it.  I think we need an actual code sample and sample input to reproduce the problem.

Comment: This is the input: http://pastebin.com/niyb3aPq  (the code uses two input files, but I just used this one two times, for testing purposes, and it doesn't even get to reading the second file, anyway). And this is the source code http://pastebin.com/Zg6eiVxR . The nasty thing happens in line 15.